# Structure defined in header file not found in C file

Tags: c

I created a header file in which I defined a structure called CtrlStruct :

```
typedef struct CtrlStruct
{
    CtrlIn *inputs;   ///< controller inputs
    CtrlOut *outputs; ///< controller outputs
    RobotPosition *rob_pos; ///< robot position
    OpponentsPosition *opp_pos; ///< opponents position
    SpeedRegulation *sp_reg; ///< speed regulation
    RobotCalibration *calib; ///< calibration
    PathPlanning *path; ///< path-planning
    Strategy *strat; ///< strategy
    int main_state; ///< main state
    int robot_id;   ///< ID of the robot
    int team_id;    ///< ID of the team
} CtrlStruct;
```

I then use this structure in my C file and I include the header in my C file (the C file and the header have the same name). Despite that, my compiler doesn't recognise this structure.

```
#include "CtrlStruct_gr7.h"
#include "namespace_ctrl.h"
#include "init_pos_gr7.h"
#include "odometry_gr7.h"
#include "opp_pos_gr7.h"
#include "speed_regulation_gr7.h"
#include "calibration_gr7.h"
#include "strategy_gr7.h"
#include "path_planning_gr7.h"
#include "ctrl_io.h"

NAMESPACE_INIT(ctrlGr7);

/*! \brief initialize the controller structure
*
* \param[in] inputs inputs of the controller
* \param[in] outputs outputs of the controller
* \return controller main structure
*
* Many parameters are set to arbitrary values, which will be corrected in 'controller_init'.
*/
CtrlStruct* init_CtrlStruct(CtrlIn *inputs, CtrlOut *outputs)
{
    int i;
    CtrlStruct* cvs;

    cvs = (CtrlStruct*)malloc(sizeof(CtrlStruct));
```

Does someone know what it is due to ?

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: Just drop the struct tag. `typedef struct CtrlStruct { ... } CtrlStruct ;` -> `typedef struct { ... } CtrlStruct;`. Since the struct is not self-referencing, you have no use of a struct tag.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't "recognise" the struct, it will issue a diagnostic (i.e. error message).  Try describing that.    Also, your example includes a lot of code (including headers, etc) that are not related to your problem.   Try cutting the code down to produce an [mcve] and there will be more chance that someone will be able to help you.

Comment: The name of C file is not relevant. The only important thing is that you include that header in the C file. Here it is probably "CtrlStruct_gr7.h". What ist `NAMESPACE_INIT(ctrlGr7);` doing?

Answer (score -2):

You have naming issue
should be:

```
struct CtrlStruct
{
CtrlIn *inputs;   ///< controller inputs
CtrlOut *outputs; ///< controller outputs
RobotPosition *rob_pos; ///< robot position
OpponentsPosition *opp_pos; ///< opponents position
SpeedRegulation *sp_reg; ///< speed regulation
RobotCalibration *calib; ///< calibration
PathPlanning *path; ///< path-planning
Strategy *strat; ///< strategy
int main_state; ///< main state
int robot_id;   ///< ID of the robot
int team_id;    ///< ID of the team
};
```

Or

```
typedef struct CtrlStruct{
CtrlIn *inputs;   ///< controller inputs
CtrlOut *outputs; ///< controller outputs
RobotPosition *rob_pos; ///< robot position
OpponentsPosition *opp_pos; ///< opponents position
SpeedRegulation *sp_reg; ///< speed regulation
RobotCalibration *calib; ///< calibration
PathPlanning *path; ///< path-planning
Strategy *strat; ///< strategy
int main_state; ///< main state
int robot_id;   ///< ID of the robot
int team_id;    ///< ID of the team
}ctrlStruct;
```

Comment: He wants to use `CtrlStruct*` Your suggested fix does not provide a typedef at all or a typedef with lowercase name. And why should he change this? His way is perfectly OK for C.

Comment: I really don't understand your answer. What's the naming issue you refere to ? He use "typedef struct name { } names;"